# What's the difference between Stress and Strain?

Tags: aircraft-design

There's a book for Engineers, entitled: 'Roark's Formulas for Stress and Strain', some describe it as 'High level Mathematics'. So what?

Comment: Stess = tensión. Strain = deformación. But this is not exactly an aviation question.

Comment: This is a pure physics question and should be asked on [physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: No, the book cited is for aeronautical engineers. Thanks. Salut +

Comment: @Urquiola what makes you think that structural mechanics in a plane are different from those in a bridge? Or algebra? Or general physics? Roark, Timoshenko, Fung, etc are part of the recommended bibliography for many engineering programmes, be they Mechanical, Civil or Aeronautical.

Comment: Despite the fact that the book is for aeronautical engineers, this is a physics question, not an aviation question. After all, aeronautical engineering involves physics.

Comment: You are wrong, question deals with aeronautics, at least with design and materials, but as the question already had a very good response, I won't accept a quarrel with you. Gesund +

Answer (score 3):

Stress is the load divided by the cross section of the material bearing it, and is expressed in units of pressure.

Strain is deformation divided by the original dimension in the direction of the deformation, and therefore is dimensionless.

Answer (score 2):

Underneath the formal definitions, the intuition is

- **stress** is what *you do to* a material;
- **strain** is what *it does* as a result.

To a first approximation they are connected by Young's modulus, which obviously varies a great deal by the material.

You can put two materials under the *same stress* (one industry standard elephant, say) and the the *strain will be very different* depending on the material (steel might exhibit less strain than rubber, for example).

Alternatively, the *same strain* (eg 10% lengthening) is achieved with *different stresses* depending on the material (eg stress of one mouse per square inch for rubber, stress of one elephant per square inch for steel).

As you can tell from the intuition above, *stress* is measured in pressure (force per area) and *strain* is dimensionless (just a proportion or percentage, or whatever).

Comment: Stress is the *cause* and strain is the *effect*... And stress/strain is Young's modulus, that is a measure of the *impedance* of the material. In the same way as, in electricity, impedance, as a general term for resistance, is tension/current, i.e., cause/effect...

Comment: I don't think I can agree with this answer. Sometimes what I do to a material is stretch it to a particular length, and what it does as a result is exert a particular amount of tension. Tuning a guitar is a good example of this, I think: you adjust the strain in order to produce the desired stress.

Comment: @TerranSwett You are confusing cause and effect; you adjust the strain by regulating the load, and therefore stress, applied. What you are saying is that you adjust the force of a spring by stretching it to a set length... well, in that case I'd ask how did you make it stretch in the first place.

Comment: @AEheresupportsMonica The causation goes both ways, doesn't it? For simplicity, imagine two balls that have opposite electric charges and which are stuck to each other. If I grab the two balls and apply an outward force to them, they will separate—stress causes strain. At the same time, however, the fact that the balls are separated causes them to exert a net force on each other—strain causes stress. It isn't an infinite regress of causation, of course, but it is a feedback loop. I don't think it's correct to label one as "the cause" and one as "the effect."

Comment: @TerranSwett that was the case which I addressed in the penultimate paragraph.